# Curl GET generating unauthorized access error

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl, grep

```
#!/bin/bash
url="https://10.10.10.10/api"
user="username"
password="password"

curl \
--insecure \
--request GET \
--header "Accept: application/json" \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--user "${user}:${password}" \
"${url}"
```

The above `bash script` is generating **Access denied error**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;}
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;}
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;}
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</h2>
  <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am able to execute the same api using same username and password via Postman.

Comment: `<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</h2>
  <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
`

Comment: i am using `user` as `domain\user` and `password` as `!Abc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Through Postman]
You can try the following:

in Postman view the request and you will find that it converted the credentials to encoded characters which is used as Authorization header, get this value and edit your bash script to:

```
#!/bin/bash
url="https://10.10.10.10/api"
user="username"
password="password"

curl \
--insecure \
--request GET \
--header "Accept: application/json" \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--header "Authorization: Basic {ValueFromPostman}" \
"${url}"
```

I hope it works for you

Comment: i am still getting `Access Denied` error. My password has special characters. I think that could be the issue. Can you please let me know how to account for the special chars in the password?

Comment: does the encrypted authorization key contain special characters ??

Comment: I am not using encrypted key and just using plaintext `user` as `domain\user` and `password` as `!Abc`

Comment: Using special characters will not affect if you use Authorization header instead, did you get it like the posted pic ?

Comment: I get your point. I am using `Authorization header` and replacing !Abc with \!Abc. but still getting `<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</h2>
  <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>

Comment: No you don't need to use username or password, Don't replace any values in postman use the password and username as they are after confirming that they are working, get the used Authorization key. If you have done that, you can try to found another solution :(

Answer (score 2):

bash arrays are nice for holding program options in a readable way. Assuming your server expects [Basic access authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication):

```
#!/bin/bash
url="https://10.10.10.10/api"
user="username"
password="password"
curl_opts=(
    --insecure 
    --request GET 
    --header "Accept: application/json" 
    --header "Content-Type: application/json" 
    --header "Authorization: Basic $( echo "$user:$password" | base64 )" 
)

curl "${curl_opts[@]}" "$url"
```

However, you might need to send your userid/password/other-client-secrets to a specific API endpoint to request a **token**, and subsequent API requests require that token. Check the docs for the API you're using.